# Symfony access headers in custom validator constraint

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to access the headers of my request in a custom validator constraint like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\CountValidator as BaseCountValidator;

final class CountValidator extends BaseCountValidator
{
    private Request $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        parent::validate($value, $constraint);
    }
}
```

But the headerBag in $this->request is always an empty array unfortunately.

Is there maybe an issue because I extend the symfony count validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ingest `RequestStack` instead of `Request`

See the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html)